# Lighttpd refusing connections and not listening at all

Tags: networking, server, lighttpd

I've been looking online for hours now, but I still can't find an answer. My lighttpd server seems to not be listening to connections at all.

Output of netstat -nsl:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::5355                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

I have no idea what is going on.